# Xamarin Forms NavigationPage.TitleView RTL, the content disappered

Tags: xamarin, mobile, xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin.forms app that supports RTL, but when i convert a Page to RTL the NavigationPage.TitleView text disapears.

The NavigationPage.TitleView Code:

```
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <Label Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource TittleLabel}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Label>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

This is the [Result screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51jhY.jpg).

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

For RTL, the Label having RTL issues. Please find the issue link below.

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3611

When setting RTL to Page, the title view is disappeared. you can report to the Xamarin team. For instead of setting a title through Label, directly setting title property of ContentPage like below,

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             Title="RTL"
             FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
```

It's working but RTL is not applying. But the title is displayed. You can report this issue also.

Answer (score 0):

I guess maybe the binding do not work. I make a sample for your reference.

MainPage.xaml

```
<StackLayout>
    <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked" Text="Title View Page" />
</StackLayout>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
 private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new TitleViewPage());
    }
```

TitleViewPage.xaml

```
 <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="TittleLabel" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Green" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Large" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label
            HorizontalOptions="Start"
            HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
            Style="{StaticResource TittleLabel}"
            Text="{Binding Title}"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            Text="Welcome to TitleView Page!"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

TitleViewPage.xaml.cs

public string Title { get; set; }
        public TitleViewPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Title = "My TitleView";
            this.BindingContext = this;
        }

App.xaml.cs

```
public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
    }
```

[image]

**Updated:**

When you set the `FlowDirection` to `RightToLeft`, the titleview could be seen on horizontal screen.

[image]

On the Right-to-left localization document, it lists the limitations.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/right-to-left

> NavigationPage button location, toolbar item location, and transition animation is controlled by the device locale, rather than the FlowDirection property.

This question has also be reported. You could follow the update . https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9083

Comment: thanks Wendy for your answer
binding working well this issue appear only when change page direction to RTL but its working fine in LTR

Comment: I have update the reply. I hopr this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

this aproach worked for me:

-set RTL-FlowDirection for main-layout (wrapper) of ContentPage's content (instead of ContentPage)

App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>

     <Style x:Key="PageTitleStyle" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="EndAndExpand"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,5,0"/>
     </Style>

  </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<ContentPage ....>

   <NavigationPage.TitleView >
        <Label Text="{Binding Title}"  Style="{StaticResource PageTitleStyle}"  />
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>

  <StackLayout FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
    ....
 </StackLayout> 

</ContentPage>
```